# ExecutorService slows down , bogs down my pc

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am writing a parser for a website , it has many pages (I call them IndexPages) . Each page has a lot of links (about 300 to 400 links in an IndexPage). I use Java's `ExecutorService` to invoke 12 `Callables` concurrently in one IndexPage. Each `Callable` just fire a http request to one link and do some parsing and db storing actions. When first IndexPage finished , program progresses to second IndexPage , until no next IndexPage found.

[image: parsing 1st page]
When running , it seems OK , I can observe the threads working/scheduling well. Each link's parsing/storing just takes about 1 to 2 seconds.

[image: After running 2 hours]
But as time goes by , I observed each `Callable`(parsing/storing) takes longer and longer. Take this picture for example , sometimes it takes 10 or more seconds to finish a `Callable` (The green bar is RUNNING , the purple bar is WAITING). And my PC is bogging down , everything becomes sluggish.

This is my main algorithm :

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);    
String indexUrl = // Set initial (1st page) IndexPage
while(true)
{
  String nextPage = // parse next page in the indexUrl

  Set<Callable<Void>> callables = new HashSet<>();
  for(String url : getUrls(indexUrl))
  {
    Callable callable = new ParserCallable(url , … and some DAOs);
    callables.add(callable);
  } 

  try {
    executorService.invokeAll(callables);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if (nextPage == null) 
    break;

  indexUrl = nextPage;
} // true
executorService.shutdown();
```

The algorithm is simple and self-explanatory. I wonder what may cause such situation ? Anyway to prevent such performance degradation ?

[image: CPU/Memory]
The CPU/Memory/Heap shows reasonable usage.

[image: Environments]
Environments , FYI.

==================== updated ====================

I've change my implementations from `ExecutorService` to `ForkJoinPool` :

```
ForkJoinPool pool=new ForkJoinPool(12);
String indexUrl = // Set initial (1st page) IndexPage
while(true)
{
  Set<Callable<Void>> callables = new HashSet<>();
  for(String url : for(String url : getUrls(indexUrl)))
  {
    Callable callable = new ParserCallable(url , DAOs...);
    callables.add(callable);
  }
  pool.invokeAll(callables);

  String nextPage = // parse next page in this indexUrl
  if (nextPage == null)
    break;

  indexUrl = nextPage;
} // true
```

It takes longer than `ExecutorService`'s solution. `ExecutorService` takes about 2 hours to finish all pages , while `ForkJoinPool` takes 3 hours , and each Callable still takes longer and longer time to complete (from 1 sec to 5,6 or even 10 seconds). I don't mind it takes longer , I just hope it takes constant time (not longer and longer) to finish a job .

I am wondering if I create a lot of (non-thread-safe) `GregorianCalendar` , `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` objects in the parser and cause some thread issue. But I didn't reuse these objects or pass them among threads. So I still cannot find the reason.

Comment: To all interested. I've upgraded my code to rxjava's solution and a new MacBookPro Retina 16G ram . The service now works perfectly. I think it's not rxjava that solve the problem. I think it is hardware's upgrade . Before upgrade to MBPr , I only have 8G ram , with C2D CPU . And rxjava's solution also bogs down the old hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the heap you have a memory issue. `ExecutorService.invokeAll` collects all of the results of the `Callable` instances into a `List` and returns that `List` when they all complete. You may want to consider simply calling `ExecutorService.submit` since you don't seem to care about the results of each `Callable`.

Comment: This would make sense if his Callables had memory leaks or weren't properly closing resources such as JDBC connections and UrlConnections.  Smallufo, could you take a look at that please?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why there is need of Callable to parse your index pages since your 'Caller' method does not expect any result from  ParserCallable. I could see you would need to bit Exception handling,but still it can be managed with `Runnable`.

When you use `Callable.call()` it would return FutureTask back ,which is never used.

You should be able to improve implementation by using Runnable which could avoid this additional operation

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
for(String url : getUrls(indexUrl))  {
  Runnable worker = new ParserRunnable(url , … and some DAOs);
  executor.execute(worker);
}

class ParserRunnable implements Runnable{
}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't see how this will have any more than a trivial effect on performance.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with Runnable , but encountered a cryptic error (Hibernate's UnknownServiceException) . It seems hibernate's session problem in multithread env, which I cannot solve it . 

It spawns another 12 thread to process page2's links , and exceptions begin thrown…

See this image for detail : http://i.imgur.com/Vcl6ME9.png .

The same code in Callable.call() works perfect. No additional threads spawn.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, if you have 40 pages, each with ~300 URLs, you will create ~12,000 Callables?  While that it probably not too many Callables, it is a lot of HTTPConnections and Database Connections.

I think you should try using one Callable per page.  You'll still gain a ton by running them in parallel.  I don't know what you are using for the HTTP request, but you might be able to reuse system resources there instead of opening and closing 12,000 of them.

And especially for the DB.  You'll have just 40 connections.  You might even be able to be super efficient by collecting the ~300 records locally, then using a batch update.

Comment: It has hundreds of page , each page has 300 to 400 links. I only spawn 12 threads to process one page. That is , maximum 12 concurrent connections fired (One Callable only fires one http connection) . After one page's links processed I progress to next page. I think it is very conservative . (Not 12000 Callables created at the same time ). I am using Jsoup.parse(url , 1000x10) to fire a http connection. http://jsoup.org

Comment: Even though only 12 are running at a time, by splitting the work into such small chunks you force there to be tens of thousands of Callables, which is probably o.k., but this also requires tens of thousands of database connections to be created and then disposed, which perhaps is a problems.  By using larger chunks of work you can use far less DB resources.  Your system of gazillions of very simple Callables is, IMO, quite simple and elegant.  Unfortunately, practical constraints on DB connections may force you to use another, less elegant solution.